# How to change struct variable content?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/wYgfLLQYdm

See example above. In my example the variable change does not last after the method is executed. How can I change a struct variable's value with a struct method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method receiver is a value, not a pointer.

That means those methods like `switch_width_height()` operate on a *copy* of the object.
See also:

- FAQ "[Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)".
- "[Don't Get Bitten by Pointer vs Non-Pointer Method Receivers in Golang](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/)"
- "[Go 101: Methods on Pointers vs. Values](http://zduck.com/2014/go-101-methods-on-pointers-vs-values/)"
- "[Go Bootcamp](http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/methods#sec-method_receivers) "

Add a '`*`':

```
func (s *square) switch_width_height()
```

And it will work as expected: see [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/_s9uA7ilDE).